# Set Route root if request comes from specific IP

Tags: nginx, laravel-4, routes

I have a Laravel 4 setup which works fine if I access it directly (say, for example, navigating to `10.1.1.4` shows the website just fine).

But we have a nginx server running which will `proxy_pass` requests to the server. The problem with this is that the `proxy_pass` will only execute if we go (for example) go to `10.1.1.5/ttt` which will work for the initial request, but all the resources / redirects will be broken (because of the missing `/ttt` while using the url generation of Laravel 4.

So my question is very simple. How can I dynamicly set the root to which will be redirected to? So if you access the website direct it will redirect like this:

```
return Redirect::to('/login');
```

But if you access it from the nginx it will redirect to:

```
return Redirect::to('/ttt/login');
```

I've already checked the `$_SERVER` variable, and `SERVER_NAME` hold the IP of the nginx. So, since that will be static, I could do a check if the `SERVER_NAME` equals the nginx IP. The problem is that I don't know what to do further. Should I create a global variable which will hold the "prefix" or is there an another way to add the `/ttt` to every url generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For people with the same problem, here's my dirty hack:*

I've created two defines in `public/index.php`

```
define('REQ_NGINX', ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == '10.1.1.5'));               // boolean
define('TTT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . (REQ_NGINX?'/ttt':'')); // without leading slash!!!
```

Then I wrapped all the routes in a `Route::group`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => REQ_NGINX ? 'ttt' : ''], function () {
    Route::get('/',             'HomeController@root');
    .....
});
```

That will prepend the `ttt` string in front of all the routes IF `REQ_NGINX` equals `true`

Then I've edited the file **vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php**:
At the end of the constructor, I've added this line:

```
$this->forceRootUrl(TTT_URL);
```

And the last step was to edit the `.htaccess` and add the following lines *BEFORE* the `RewriteCond` of `index.php`

```
# Handle css, js, img...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|eot|svg|ttf|woff)$
RewriteRule ^ttt/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

That will strip the ttt part away for css,js... files

I hope this self answer will help somebody in the future having this same problem. Been working on this problem for way to long. Nevertheless, if you have found a better / cleaner solution, don't hesitate to answer this question.